# Unable to train PyTorch model in GPU. Keep getting errors that tensors are not on same device

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been stuck at trying to train my PyTorch model in GPU. The model perfectly works in CPU though. I have been using Google Colab's GPU resources for using cuda.

I know that in order to run a model in GPU, the 'model', 'input features' and 'target' needs to be in 'cuda' device.

But, no matter what I do in my code, I either keep getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu
```

**OR**

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

Here is my notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rviS_4hmdzPQUncZyi8FsRH7y3jL0isQ

It would be really helpful if someone could let me exactly which variables to be moved using `.to('cuda')`

Additionally, explanations/suggestions for ensuring that this does not recur in the future would be highly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: it seems like you move your variables correctly to GPU. Are you moving the model to GPU?

Comment: @Shai I did try the `model.to('cuda')`. My error seem to be mentioning that my 'hidden' tensor is not in the same device as the input tensor. Tried all combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.hidden` is a tuple of `torch.tensors`. PyTorch doesn't automatically move these kind of tensor to GPU when `.to(device)` is invoked on your model.

You can either:

1. Implement your own `to(self, type, device)` method for your `BiLSTM_CRF` class. (Not recommended).
2. Make `self.hidden` a registered [buffer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer). This way all methods of `nn.Module` such as `.to()`, `.float()`, etc. will also be applied to `self.hidden`.

Comment: I understand the former. For the latter, can you please provide an example code for my case? Unable to make out using the example in the doc. Thanks!

Comment: @Parsh you are using `self.hidden` in a very weird manner. You actually call `self.init_hidden()` for every `forward` pass. In that case, why make these two tensors members of `BiLSTM_CRF` in the first place?

Comment: @Parsh (1) remove `self.hidden` from your code. (2) add `device` argument to the method `self.init_hidden`. (3) in `self._get_lstm_features` call `self.init_hidden` with the proper device.

Answer (score 0):

first you have configure the device you want to use, if you are on GPU change it to CPU and the reverse is also true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).